# My autoencoder was not learning to predict value [Updated]

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to work on building a variational autoencoder in Keras, with an input shape of X= (1,50) and Y= (1,20).

I have uploaded the DataSet, [you can download it from here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tp3dr1dxdml454zjuepin/DataSet.rar?rlkey=wazw1m29ck4400x6fg5aetl2z&dl=0).

I made 1 input, and I want to make relation between the input and output. ( the data is 1 dimension of binary cases). but always I found these results:

[image]

I tried changing activation and loss and no positive results.

```
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K, optimizers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.optimizers

# Function for reparameterization trick
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

# Load your data
# Note: Replace this with your actual data loading
# training_feature = X
# ground_truth_r = Y

original_dim = 32  # Adjust according to your data shape
latent_dim = 32

# Encoder network
inputs_x = Input(shape=(original_dim, ), name='encoder_input')
inputs_x_dropout = Dropout(0.25)(inputs_x)
inter_x1 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')(inputs_x_dropout)
inter_x2 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')(inter_x1)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(inter_x2)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(inter_x2)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = Model(inputs_x, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')


# Decoder network for reconstruction
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
inter_y1 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')(latent_inputs)
inter_y2 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')(inter_y1)

outputs_reconstruction = Dense(original_dim)(inter_y2)  # original_dim should be 32
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs_reconstruction, name='decoder')
decoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')


from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import  BatchNormalization

# Predictor network
# Start of the predictor model
latent_input_for_predictor = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))

# Building the predictor model using the functional API
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(latent_input_for_predictor)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
predictor_output = Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='linear')(x)  # Adjust the output dimension as per your requirement




if ( 1 == 1): 
  # Create the model
  predictor = Model(inputs=latent_input_for_predictor, outputs=predictor_output)

  # Compile the model
  optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
  predictor.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])




  # Train the reconstruction model
  history_reconstruction = decoder.fit(X, X, epochs=100, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, validation_data=(XX, XX))


  latent_representations = encoder.predict(X)[2]
  #vae.fit([training_feature_sk,training_score],            epochs=epochs,             batch_size=batch_size, verbose = 0)
  # Train the prediction model
  history_prediction = predictor.fit(latent_representations, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, validation_data=(encoder.predict(XX)[2], YY))




  # Save models and plot training/validation loss
  encoder.save("BrmEnco_Updated.h5", overwrite=True)
  decoder.save("BrmDeco_Updated.h5", overwrite=True)
  predictor.save("BrmPred_Updated.h5", overwrite=True)

  plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

  plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
  plt.plot(history_reconstruction.history['loss'], label='Decoder Training Loss')
  plt.plot(history_reconstruction.history['val_loss'], label='Decoder Validation Loss')
  plt.title('Decoder Loss')
  plt.ylabel('Loss')
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.legend()

  plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
  plt.plot(history_prediction.history['loss'], label='Predictor Training Loss')
  plt.plot(history_prediction.history['val_loss'], label='Predictor Validation Loss')
  plt.title('Predictor Loss')
  plt.ylabel('Loss')
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.legend()

  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran it on some `digits` images in `sklearn`, so I increased the input shape from 32 to 36, and set the `predictor` output shape to 10 classes. I normalised the input data and used a smaller batch size.

Input data X is a 36-dimensional *binary* vector (e.g. sample 0 = [1 0 1 0 ...]) and y is a 9-dimensional multilabel indicator target. The multilabel information is y is: [is odd?, is prime?, is multiple of 3?, ...].

I used binary cross-entropy loss for both X and Y. This is to strongly penalise wrong digits. Both the decoder and prediction outputs are `sigmoid`. I removed the dropout layer as it seemed to hurt performance, and threw in some batch norm layers. I used the NAdam optimizer.

I run `.fit` for 1 epoch, and then manually calculate the train and validation accuracies, before running the next epoch. Initially I was using Keras' accuracy values, but found them to be incorrect for some outputs.

[image]

Loss and accuracy curves:

[image]

The solid lines are loss, and show that the model is converging. The model memorises the train Y (dotted orange - 100%), and on the validation Y it gets about 70% right (dashed orange). So its performance with Y is quite good. It doesn't perfectly reconstruct X - it gets X exactly right about 50% of the time (dotted blue), and on the validation X it only gets it exactly right <5% of the time (dashed blue).

Although its reconstructions seem to have relatively low accuracy, this is because if only a single digit is wrong in the 36-dim reconstruction, it is considered incorrect (according to the metric specified in the comments). Its actual reconstructions are close to the originals and look quite good. Even though it doesn't get X exactly right, it is often very close, differing by a pixel here or there:

left: original X train, right: reconstruction
[image]

Since the reconstructions are close to the originals, to me that suggests the latent space is not bad, and is perhaps usable. I think something to consider is whether X needs to be exact if one is interpolating (i.e. making up new values) in latent space.

```
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn import set_config
set_config(transform_output='default')

#Set the random seed for consistent results
import random
random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
#clear session for each run
K.clear_session()

#
#Load digits data
#
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

digits = load_digits()
X, Y_original = digits['data'], digits['target']

#Create a multilabel-indicator Y: each y is a 9-dim *binary* vector
Y_original = Y_original.reshape(-1, 1).astype(int)
Y_multilabel = np.empty((Y_original.shape[0], 9))
for idx, y in enumerate(Y_original):
    is_odd = bool(y % 2)
    is_prime = True if y in [1, 3, 5, 7] else False
    is_multiple_3 = True if y in [3, 6, 9] else False
    is_large = True if y >= 5 else False
    is_extreme = True if y in [0, 9] else False
    binary_digits = [int(d) for d in bin(y[0] ** 2 + 10)[-4:]] #last 4 digits
    
    Y_multilabel[idx, :] = np.array([
        is_odd, is_prime, is_multiple_3, is_large, is_extreme] + binary_digits
    ).astype(int)

Y = Y_multilabel

#Create a 32-dim binary X
X = X.reshape(-1, 8, 8)[:, 1:-1, 1:-1].reshape(-1, 36)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
X = np.where(X < 0, 0, 1) #make X binary

input_dim = X.shape[1]
multilabel_size = Y_multilabel.shape[1]

#View some samples
f, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(4, 4), layout='tight')
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
    ax.imshow(X[i, :].reshape(6, 6), cmap='binary')
    ax.axis('off')
    y_label = str(Y[i].astype(int)).replace(' ', '')[1:-1]
    ax.set_title(y_label, fontsize=8)
f.suptitle('Samples from normalised digits data', fontsize=10)
plt.show()

# reparameterization trick
# instead of sampling from Q(z|X), sample eps = N(0,I)
# z = z_mean + sqrt(var)*eps
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    # by default, random_normal has mean=0 and std=1.0
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    thre = K.random_uniform(shape=(batch,1))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

# Define VAE model components
intermediate_dim = 32 // 1
latent_dim = 32 // 1

# Encoder network
inputs_x = Input(shape=input_dim, name='encoder_input')
# inputs_x_dropout = Dropout(0.25)(inputs_x)
inputs_x_dropout = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inputs_x)
inputs_x_dropout = BatchNormalization()(inputs_x_dropout)
inputs_x_dropout = Dense(512, activation='relu')(inputs_x_dropout)
inputs_x_dropout = BatchNormalization()(inputs_x_dropout)
inputs_x_dropout = Dense(224, activation='relu')(inputs_x_dropout)

inputs_x_dropout = BatchNormalization()(inputs_x_dropout)
inter_x1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputs_x_dropout)
inter_x2 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(inter_x1)

z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(inter_x2)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(inter_x2)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = Model(inputs_x, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')

# Decoder network for reconstruction
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
inter_y1 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)

inter_y1 = Dense(224, activation='relu')(inter_y1)
inter_y1 = BatchNormalization()(inter_y1)
inter_y1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(inter_y1)
inter_y1 = BatchNormalization()(inter_y1)
inter_y1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(inter_y1)
inter_y1 = BatchNormalization()(inter_y1)

inter_y2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inter_y1)
outputs_reconstruction = Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(inter_y2)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs_reconstruction, name='decoder')

# Separate network for multilabel indicator prediction from inter_y2
outputs_prediction = Dense(multilabel_size, activation='sigmoid')(inter_y2)
predictor = Model(latent_inputs, outputs_prediction, name='predictor')

# Instantiate VAE model with two outputs
outputs_vae = [decoder(z), predictor(z)]
vae = Model(inputs_x, outputs_vae, name='vae_mlp')
vae.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Train the model
val_size = 360 #20% val size

X_trn = X[:val_size]
Y_trn = Y[:val_size]

X_val = X[-val_size:]
Y_val = Y[-val_size:]

from collections import defaultdict
metrics = defaultdict(list)

for epoch in range(70):
    history = vae.fit(X_trn, [X_trn, Y_trn], batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

    h = history.history
    metrics['trn_predictor_loss'].extend(h['predictor_loss'])
    metrics['trn_decoder_loss'].extend(h['decoder_loss'])
    metrics['trn_loss'].extend(h['loss'])
    
    #Manually calculate accuracy for trn and val
    for mode in ['trn', 'val']:
        XY = [X_trn, Y_trn] if mode == 'trn' else [X_val, Y_val]
        n_samples = len(XY[0])
        
        soft_recon, soft_pred = vae.predict(XY[0])
        
        hard_recon = (soft_recon > 0.5).astype(int)
        hard_pred = (soft_pred > 0.5).astype(int)
        
        recon_acc = sum(
            [np.array_equal(xhat, x) for xhat, x in zip(hard_recon, XY[0])]
        ) / n_samples * 100
        
        pred_acc = sum(
            [np.array_equal(yhat, y) for yhat, y in zip(hard_pred, XY[1])]
        ) / n_samples * 100
        
        metrics[mode + '_decoder_acc'].append(recon_acc)
        metrics[mode + '_predictor_acc'].append(pred_acc)

plt.plot(metrics['trn_loss'], 'C3', lw=2, label='loss')
plt.plot(metrics['trn_decoder_loss'], 'C0', lw=2, label='loss | decoder')
plt.plot(metrics['trn_predictor_loss'], 'C1', lw=2, label='loss | predictor')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.ylabel('loss')

ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()
ax2.plot(metrics['trn_decoder_acc'], 'C0', ls=':', label='trn acc | decoder')
ax2.plot(metrics['trn_predictor_acc'], 'C1', ls=':', label='trn acc | predictor')

ax2.plot(metrics['val_decoder_acc'], 'C0', ls='--', label='val acc | decoder')
ax2.plot(metrics['val_predictor_acc'], 'C1', ls='--', label='val acc | predictor')
ax2.set_ylabel('accuracy (%)')
plt.gcf().legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 1.1), ncol=2)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 4)

soft_recon, soft_pred = vae.predict(X)

#Convert soft predictions (probabilities) to hard binary 0/1
recon_binary = soft_recon > 0.5
pred_binary = soft_pred > 0.5

f, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=25, ncols=2, figsize=(3, 35))
axs = axs.flatten()
for i, ax in zip(range(1, len(axs), 2), (axs[1::2])):
    ax.imshow(recon_binary[i, :].reshape(6, 6), cmap='binary')
    axs[i - 1].imshow(X[i, :].reshape(6, 6), cmap='binary')
    
    y_multilabel = str(Y[i].astype(int)).replace(' ', '')[1:-1]
    yhat = str(pred_binary[i].astype(int)).replace(' ', '')[1:-1]
    ax.set_title('$\hat{y}$:' + yhat + '\n$y$:' + y_multilabel,
                 fontsize=8, fontproperties={'family': 'monospace'})
# f.suptitle('Digit reconstructions and predictions', fontsize=10)
[ax.axis('off') for ax in axs]
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: My accuracy is very low always 0.02 
My data is a vector of binary values

Comment: Could you provide some data for me to try? I created some test data above and it seemed to work with that.

Comment: It is private data 
the X is binary vector of (1,32) dim 
and the Y is a binary vector of (1,16) dim 
The problem is the predictor not learn and the predictor training loss always higher than predictor validation loss ... I will update the code and share the rsults

Comment: When you say *binary vector*, does that mean each sample (row) of `X` is 32, and only *one* of those 32 is 1, rest are 0? E.g. something like sample 0 = `[<31 zeros> ... 1]`. Same for `y`? Could you report `X.shape` and `y.shape`?

Comment: No it is mean all the vector is composed of 0 or 1 
example [0,1,1,0,0,....] [1,0,0,1,0,....] ...etc

Comment: Is it the same for `y` - i.e. each sample/row from `y` is something like `[0 0 1 1 ... 1 0]`?

Comment: Yes exactly  they are the same

Comment: Yes they are the same 
The problem for me is the predictor can't predict the Y ... always did mistakes in 3 bits and the MSE always 0.19922966982005635

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256375/discussion-between-user3128-and-stevgates).

Comment: Can u help me to turn this code no classification ? because I should work on regression !!! please

Comment: X and Y should be integers, rather than a string binary inputs/outputs?

Comment: No should be Binary, but I am not doing Classification ... it is regression 
In my field there are many machines, each machine product X and Y 
So I want to use to fit  X and Y ( my dataset )
The other machine can give another dataset X1 and Y1, and I want to use the same model to find a relation between X1 and Y1 ... do u understand me know ?

Comment: the input is a vector not image ! 
and for each X there Y 
for another dataset for example X1 <=> Y1 
X2 <=> Y2 
But know I am focusing only on one data set wich is X and Y ...

Comment: I have uploaded the dataset ... it is not picture please take a look

Comment: Have you considered trying a recurrent/sequence-based autoencoder instead? If your input has characteristics of a sequence, it might perform better. Some pseudo-code is on this page for an LSTM autoencoder under "Sequence-to-sequence autoencoder": https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html